# Is there a way to download all dependencies in a package-lock.json/yarn.lock file without installing them?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, package-lock.json

I am trying to stage dependencies from the NPM registry in a Nexus NPM proxy repository for any arbitrary JavaScript project. I can perform an `npm install` or `yarn install` which will cause all the dependencies to be staged, but I'd like to avoid that. The main reason is I want to avoid needing the necessary C/C++ libraries installed to compile the dependencies that are NodeJS C/C++ add-ons.

The only solution I can think of is by parsing the package-lock.json/yarn.lock file and running `npm pack <dependency>` for each dependency, which will cause npm to fetch the needed dependency and copy the tarball of the dependency to the current directory. I could then delete each downloaded tarball.

Is there a more elegant solution for either npm or yarn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `npm install --ignore-scripts` then the install scripts will be ignored and so any C/C++ files won't be built anymore.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like yarn also has this option, so it should work for both cases.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you!